# Android TCP sending data

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, send

Let's say i want to have one Socket connection with a server, for receiving and sending data. After that Socket is created, i want to keep sending data trough it and at the same time receive. My current code isn't working and code examples will be greatly appreciated.Thank you. My current code:

```
public static PrintWriter outToServer;
private static Socket clientSocket;
public static BufferedReader inFromServer;
public static void register(InetAddress ip, int port, String name) {
try {
    clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
    outToServer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
    inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

      new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            receive();
        }
    }).start();
    send("reg:" + name);
    }   catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
 //That method is called many times after "send("reg:" + name);"
public static void send(String str) {
        outToServer.println(str);
}
private static void receive() {
   try{
    while (true) {
      String str = inFromServer.readLine();
   }
  } catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The Server code:

```
   class TCPServer {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
 String clientSentence;
 ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9876);
 while (true) {
  Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
  BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
  clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
  System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: How can you be sure you are receiving anything? You have no output in the `receive()` method. Also, I don't believe this compiles. When you call `new Thread().start` with no `()`. inFromServer.readLine() should also be able to throw IOException

Comment: Fixed. I want to make the sending work first, and then deal with receiving.

Comment: You need to stop reading when `readLine()` returns null.

Comment: @EJP Will an if in received do the job? Also how could this be causing problems with sending

Comment: Of course an `if` will do the job, or, more usually, a `while`: `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)`. I don't remember saying that this could be causing problems with sending. It was posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the call to flush() after sending your message.

Try this:

```
public static void send(String str) {
    outToServer.println(str);
    outToServer.flush();
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
private boolean _run = false;
private PrintWriter _bufferOut;
private BufferedReader _bufferIn;

public static void register(InetAddress ip, int port, String name) {
    _run = true;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(_run) {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
                    try {
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                        _bufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw), true);
                        _bufferIn = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        sendMessage("reg:" + name);
                        while (_run) {
                            String msg = _bufferIn.readLine();
                            // do whatever with the message
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) { socket.close(); continue; }
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void stop() {
    _run = false;
    if (_bufferOut != null) { _bufferOut.flush(); _bufferOut.close(); }
    _bufferIn = null; _bufferOut = null;
}

public void sendMessage(String msg) {
    if (_bufferOut == null || _bufferOut.checkError()) return;
    _bufferOut.println(msg); _bufferOut.flush();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Server:

```
class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9876);
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Received: " + inFromClient.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Multiuser Server:

```
class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9876);
        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("Received: " + inFromClient.readLine());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Unfortunately, like my current code only the `sendMessage("reg:" + name);` is received. I see some traffic activity in android studio when sending the others(after `sendMessage("reg:"+name)`), but none is received by the server...

Comment: He used this constructor in the code http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean) which sets autoflush to true.

Comment: Can you post the code for the server. It might be that the server is not receiving properly... The code I posted I have use successfully in another project.

Comment: I believe the problem is in the server. The statement "Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();" blocks until you get a new connection. You have added this line inside your while loop. Therefore your code will only receive the first message. Instead, try moving it out of the loop. If you want to enable multiple connections, launch a thread for each of the incoming connections.

Comment: I added the modifications above ;)

Comment: Yes. The problem turned out to be with the server, because i tried using SocketTest v 3.0.0 and it works. The server code gives compilation errors, but when i fix them it doesn't display anything. Thanks again for the help!